# Install test app on surface hub

Tags: uwp, surface-hub

Is it possible to install an UWP test app on the surface hub, without going through the store, and without Visual Studio?

My client wants to demo the unfinished application, so I can't publish it to the store. I also don't have a Surface Hub device yet...

I already have an .appxbundle package, that is signed and can be deployed on mobile phones and other PCs without the store by installing the certificate and then installing the .appxbundle.

Is this possible?

Comment: From what I remember you can deploy to the remote end but the device must have developer mode enabled. It should be in the build settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install test apps on Surface Hub, you can refer to [Install apps on your Microsoft Surface Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/install-apps-on-surface-hub), especially the [Develop and test apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/install-apps-on-surface-hub#develop-and-test-apps) section.

Firstly, you need **turn on developer mode**:

> 1. From your Surface Hub, start **Settings**.
> 2. Type the device admin credentials when prompted.
> 3. Navigate to **Update & security** > **For developers**.
> 4. Select **Developer mode** and accept the warning prompt.

Then you can deploy your app with either [**Visual Studio**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-surface-hub-apps-using-visual-studio#deploy-apps-to-a-surface-hub-from-visual-studio) or [**Provisioning package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/provisioning-packages-for-certificates-surface-hub#create-the-provisioning-package).

> **Visual Studio**
>
> During development, the easiest way to test your app on a Surface Hub is using Visual Studio. Visual Studio's remote debugging feature helps you discover issues in your app before deploying it broadly. For more information, see [Test Surface Hub apps using Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-surface-hub-apps-using-visual-studio).
>
> **Provisioning package**
>
> Use Visual Studio to [create an app package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh454036.aspx) for your UWP app, signed using a test certificate. Then use Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer (ICD) to create a provisioning package containing the app package. For more information, see [Create provisioning packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-hub/provisioning-packages-for-certificates-surface-hub).

Comment: @Jay Zuo When creating provsioning package (Advanced Provisioning), I cant brows and add appx bundle to it. While creating package , I have selected No in the first dialog asking if you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store.Is that the reason?