# Provisioning package with UWP application is not installed on the last Windows 10 and Windows 10 Team version

Tags: windows, windows-10-universal, provisioning, surface-hub

I need to test a UWP application on a Surface Hub device with Windows 10 Team OS to which I do not have direct access. As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43866168/install-test-app-on-surface-hub)  application can be installed via a provisioning package. Unfortunately when I try to install the provisioning package with my UWP app installation fails.

I tried packaging different applications via [Windows Configuration Designer](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productid/9NBLGGH4TX22?ocid=pdpshare) but ultimately got the same result, provisioning fails on Surface Hub with Windows 10 Team OS and on desktop Windows 10 devices.
Every package I tested installs successfully on Windows 11 devices and on one device with the old Windows 10 version.

I tested on application packages downloaded from the Microsoft Store via https://store.rg-adguard.net/ and using Blank App from Visual Studio template for the UWP application.

Developer mode was enabled for all devices and every device can install and launch .Appxbundle or .Msixbundle packaged apps separately.

I get two different errors in Event Viewer under Microsoft-Windows-DeviceManagement-Enterprise-Diagnostics-Provider/Admin

The first one appears three times:

```
MDM ConfigurationManager: Command failure status. Configuraton Source ID: (ed3dde87-f804-4348-a7a3-48bd0b8329d0), Enrollment Type: (Provisioning), CSP Name: (EnterpriseModernAppManagement), Command Type: (Add: from Replace or Add), CSP URI: (./device/Vendor/MSFT/EnterpriseModernAppManagement/AppInstallation/Microsoft.MSPaint_8wekyb3d8bbwe), Result: (Unknown Win32 Error code: 0x82aa0002).
```

Code in HexInt1: 0x82aa0002

The second one always appears last:

```
MDM Declared Configuration: Function (checkNewInstanceData) operation (Read isNewInstanceData) failed with (The parameter is incorrect.)
```

Code in HRESULT: 0x80070057.

To create provisioning packages I use the Advanced Provisioning option in Windows Configuration Designer and add DeviceContextApp under UniversallAppInstall, for testing I use .Appxbundle Application File of [Paint3D](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productid/9NBLGGH5FV99?ocid=pdpshare)
 app downloaded from https://store.rg-adguard.net/ or Blank UWP app .Msixbundle from Visual Studio template. Nothing else is set in the provisioning packages.

Provisioning packages failed to install on these Windows versions

- Windows 10 Team Version 22H2 (OS build 19045.3393)
- Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (OS build 19045.3448)
- Windows 10 Pro 22H2 (OS build 19045.3570)

Provisioning packages installed successfully on:

- Windows 11 Home (OS build 22H2 22621.2428)
- Windows 10 IoT Enterprise Version 1909 (OS build 18363.1377)